# Explicitly acquire a lock from a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking

I have a running thread. I want to acquire a lock from it. I want to do it explicitly, not in a method signature or something alike. How can I do it? I mean sometimes my thread need to acquire more than one lock at once and using `synchronized(lock)` or method signature to acquire a lock won`t be appropriate. I suppose there are must be something like `CurrentThread.acquireTheLock(lock);`. And I will be able to write

```
CurrentThread.acquireTheLock(lock1);
CurrentThread.acquireTheLock(lock2);
```

Comment: Don't say, "I want to acquire a lock from it," say, "I want it to acquire a lock."  IMO, the best way to reason about threads it to imagine that the threads are the actors that _do_ things, and the methods are merely the instructions that tell them what to do.

Comment: You can use Semaphores instead of locks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a ReentrantLock.

```
ReentrantLock lock1 = new ReentrantLock();
ReentrantLock lock2 = new ReentrantLock();

public void DoSomething()
{
    lock1.lock();
    lock2.lock();
    try {
         //critical section
    } finally {
         lock1.unlock();
         lock2.unlock();
    }    
}
```

Comment: If Thread1 already called `lock.lock();` and didn\`t call `lock.unlock();` and Thread2 calls `lock.lock();`, Thread2 will do nothing and will wait untill Thread1 calls `lock.unlock();` and after it happens Thread2 will just continue its execution. Did I get it right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. That means that lock.lock() can block the execution of the Thread for some time.